# SIFT Fisher Vector GMM

Tags: matlab, classification, sift, gmm

I am trying to extract SIFT Features with vl_feat implementation in Matlab and compute then the GMM model as well as the Fisher Vector. I have two subsets train and test images from DTD Dataset.

1. run vl_sift on each split (train&test) and save the 128xN Features
2. Apply the cell Array each consists of 128xN Features to vl_gmm and get for each Feature [mean covarinace weight] and then apply the Features with calculated gmm model values to vl_fisher for each Feature.
3. Make PCA
4. Put all in SVM

My problem is that I dont know in step 2. how to transform the Feature values of each image to fit in into vl_gmm and vl_fisher.

Here is my code:

```
%% SIFT Feature Extraction

FV_train = cell(size(train_name, 1), 1);
FV_test = cell(size(test_name, 1), 1);

parfor_progress(size(train_name, 1));

parfor n = 1:size(train_name, 1) 

[~, FV_train{n}] = vl_sift(single(histeq(imresize(rgb2gray(imread(strcat(pwd, '/DTD/images', '/', train_name{n}))), [512 512]))));
[~, FV_test{n}] = vl_sift(single(histeq(imresize(rgb2gray(imread(strcat(pwd, '/DTD/images', '/', test_name{n}))), [512 512]))));
parfor_progress;

end

parfor_progress(0);

FV_train = FV_train(~cellfun('isempty',FV_train));
FV_test = FV_test(~cellfun('isempty',FV_test));

FV_train = adaptFV(FV_train);
FV_test = adaptFV(FV_test);

parfor n = 1:size(FV_train, 1) 

FV_train{n} = double(reshape(FV_train{n},1,size(FV_train{n},2)*size(FV_train{n},1)));
FV_test{n} = double(reshape(FV_test{n},1,size(FV_test{n},2)*size(FV_test{n},1)));

end
```

There exists two other problems:

- One ist that SIFT fails on some images, therefore I rejected them
- Due to the fact of the different dimensionality of SIFT Feature I have taken the longest one and fill the others with zeros to an 1xN Feature Vector.